# Kubernetes - Communicate between namspaces and services

Tags: docker, service, kubernetes, namespaces, cluster-computing

I have a pod running in namespace X under Service A.
I have a pod running a REST API in namespace Y under Service B.

How do i set up this communication?

Thank you.

Comment: [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) in the Kubernetes documentation are probably good starting points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the full name of the service.

`<TARGET_SERVICE_NAME>.<TARGET_NAMESPACE_NAME>.svc.cluster.local`

Now using your example :

```
curl B.Y.svc.cluster.local

RESPONSE FROM THE SERVICE B IN NAMESPACE Y
```

It will work from anywhere in the cluster but is dependent to the namespace.

---

You can also use **[external name](https://akomljen.com/kubernetes-tips-part-1/)** which is a bit more complicated but should deal with your problem too.